# Contravariant interfaces method dispatch/selection C#

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, contravariance, method-resolution-order

Consider the following code:

```
interface ITest<in T>
{
    void DoTest(T instance);
}

class A {}
class B : A {}
class C : B {}

class Test : ITest<A>, ITest<B>
{
    void ITest<A>.DoTest(A instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
    
    void ITest<B>.DoTest(B instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ITest<C> test = new Test();
        test.DoTest(new C());
    }
}
```

The output is:

*Void ITest<A>.DoTest(A)*

To me this is not the expected behavior, or at least not the one most developers are expecting. The expected output is:

*Void ITest<B>.DoTest(B)*

Here the "best" implementation should be used, with best meaning the generic interface with the most derived type parameter up to the contravariant "static" type.

Instead it seems the "worst" is chosen.

Inspecting the generated IL doesn't unveil the selection mechanism as the call is dispatched through the correct static type so I assume it's up to the CLR to select the implementation:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void Main () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
    // Code size 20 (0x14)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class ITest`1<class C>
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void Test::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: newobj instance void C::.ctor()
    IL_000d: callvirt instance void class ITest`1<class C>::DoTest(!0)
    IL_0012: nop
    IL_0013: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Why it acts like this? What are the rules in this case? How does it work behind the scenes?

Comment: Hint: swap the order of `ITest<A>` and `ITest<B>` in the interface list on `Test`. Still trying to find out where in the spec this is specified

Comment: I think this is dealt with in section II.12.2 of ECMA-335, but still trying to get my head around how your example matches the ones listed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified in Section II.12.2 of [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/).

Relevant snippets of the spec follows:

> Where there are multiple implementations for a given interface method due to differences in type
> parameters, the declaration order of the interfaces on the class determines which method is invoked.
> ...
> The **inheritance/implements tree** for a type T is the n-ary tree formed as follows:
>
> - The root of the tree is T
>   ...
> - If T has one or more explicit interfaces, I<sub>x</sub>, then the  inheritance/implements tree for each I<sub>x</sub> is a child of the root node, in order.
>
> The **type declaration order** of the interfaces and super classes of a type T is the
> postorder depth-first traversal of the inheritance/implements tree of type T with any
> second and subsequent duplicates of any type omitted. Occurrences of the same
> interface with different type parameters are not considered duplicates

So we've defined the **type declaration order** as the order in which these interfaces appear in the class declaration.

> When an interface method is invoked, the VES shall use the following algorithm to determine the appropriate method to call:
>
> - Beginning with the runtime class of the instance through which the interface method
>   is invoked, using its interface table as constructed above, and substituting generic
>   arguments, if any, specified on the invoking class:
>
>   1. For each method in the list associated with the interface method, if there exists a
>      method whose generic type arguments match exactly for this instantiation (or
>      there are no generic type parameters), then call the first method
>   2. Otherwise, if there exists a method in the list whose generic type parameters
>      have the correct variance relationship, then call the first such method in the list

This is saying that if there's no exact match, then take the first method in the **type declaration order** whose type parameters have the correct variance relationship.

Your example appears as **Case 6** in the section "II.12.2.1 Interface Implementation Examples", where the type `S4<V>` implements both `IVarImpl` (which means implementing `IVar<A>`) and `IVar<B>`, and the example shows that calling the method `IVar<C>::P(C)` on an instance of `S4<A>` results in the method `S1<A,B>::P(!0:A)` (that is, `void P(A)`) being called.

Indeed, if we swap the order of `ITest<A>` and `ITest<B>` in the declaration of `Test`, we can see that the `ITest<B>.DoTest(B instance)` implementation ends up being called.